# What's the difference of UseParallelGC between Java6 and Java 7

Tags: garbage-collection, java-7, java-6, jvm-arguments

Now I'm using the jvm parameter UseParallelGC, and I want to upgrade my jvm version to Java 7. Is there any difference between java 6 and java 7? Any one has some experience on it?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any usability changes when using the ParallelGC between Java 6 and Java 7. But, you can expect a better GC performance when switching to Java 7. I am using `-XX:+UseParallelOldGC` and have been upgrading just recently. Java 7 gave me several percentages of throughput and reduced the total GC time. Of course, your mileage can vary.

The main GC changes between Java 6 and 7 concern the G1 collector, the ParallelGC collector remained more or less the same with some bug fixes and minor improvements.